# Finding Detail Based on date in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services

I have a Table that I am using to pull order details in SSRS that has when the price of a product number was changed.  It has Data Changed and Updated Cost.

I am pairing up two different tables to create a report that is the cost of the package at the time of the order. Here is how I am pulling my data:

```
SELECT
  WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ItemNo AS [ActPkgCostHist ItemNo]
  ,WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ActPkgCostDate
  ,WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ActPkgCost
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.OrderNo
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.ItemNo AS [OrderHist ItemNo]
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.DispenseDt
FROM
  WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist
  INNER JOIN ORDER.OrderHist
    ON WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ItemNo = ORDER.OrderHist.ItemNo
```

Catalog=ShippedOrders

ActPkgCostHist Table has What the cost of an Item was and what date the cost was changed.

OrderHist Table has the complete details of the order except the ActPkgCost at the time of the purchase.

I am attempting to create a table that Has order number, the date of the order and the package cost at the time of the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each item in each order you have to find the latest cost date and use it when joining with the cost table

```html
SELECT C.ItemNo AS [ActPkgCostHist ItemNo], 
   C.ActPkgCostDate, 
   C.ActPkgCost, 
   O.OrderNo, 
   O.ItemNo AS [OrderHist ItemNo], 
   O.DispenseDt 
FROM   WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist AS C 
   -- JOIN order detail with cost table in order to define the cost date per item/order
   INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(CH.ActPkgCostDate) AS ItemCostDate, 
                      OH.OrderNo, 
                      OH.ItemNo, 
                      OH.DispenseDt 
               FROM   WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist AS CH 
                      INNER JOIN ORDER.OrderHist AS OH 
                              ON CH.ItemNo = OH.ItemNo 
               -- Get the latest cost date only from dates before order date
               WHERE  CH.ActPkgCostDate <= OH.DispenseDt 
               GROUP  BY OH.OrderNo, 
                         OH.ItemNo, 
                         OH.DispenseDt) AS O 
           ON C.ItemNo = O.ItemNo 
              AND C.ActPkgCostDate = O.ItemCostDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ROW_NUMBER` function is very useful for cases like this.

```
SELECT WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ItemNo AS [ActPkgCostHist ItemNo]
  ,WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ActPkgCostDate
  ,WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist.ActPkgCost
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.OrderNo
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.ItemNo AS [OrderHist ItemNo]
  ,ORDER.OrderHist.DispenseDt
FROM ORDER.OrderHist
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ItemNo, ActPkgCostDate, ActPkgCost
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY ActPkgCostDate DESC) as RN
  FROM WAREHOUSE.ActPkgCostHist
  --if there are future dated changes, limit ActPkgCostDate to be <= the current date
) ActPkgCostHist on ActPkgCostHist.ItemNo = OrderHist.ItemNo
WHERE RN = 1
```

What this subquery does is group the cost history by `ItemNo`. Then for each one, it ranks the changes by recency with the most recent change being 1. Then in the main query you filter it to just rows with a 1.

Comment: I am still a novice when it comes to SSRS.  Is there any way to space that out a little better?  I copied the text, pasted it and got a syntax error.

Comment: You can try poorsql.com to format it. Are you using SSMS to run it? It will usually highlight the line with the error. Also, is this SQL Server or some other flavor of SQL?

Comment: I am using SSRS 3.0 to run it.  poorsql.com was very helpful.